# Is there a fix for task hijacking on Android <10?

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, android-security, android-task

I was reading this article about task hijacking on Android: https://blog.dixitaditya.com/android-task-hijacking/

I tried the recommend fix but can still reproduce the issue. I also tried specifying package names of Instagram, Gmail app as **android:taskAffinity** value in the malicious app's Android Manifest and it redirected me to malicious app after clicking Instagram, Gmail. So, how come Gmail and Instagram is vulnerable to this or am i mistaking somewhere?

Is there a proper fix for this issue on Android?

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you to understand `task`, `launchModes` and `taskAffinity`.
Here's a [google doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) about these topics.

As a solution; you can use `singleInstance`. They are pretty similar, only difference is that, `singleInstance` keeps only one activity and even if you have multiple activities in back stack, they don't seem in different tasks, so that you see only one task in your `Recents` screen.

Answer (score 0):

I see that a lot of apps are vulnerable for that. Only `launchMode="singleInstance"` or `taskAffinity="..."` protects against that, but it breaks many android features regarding activities navigation.

I'm really surprised that such serious vulnerability which was detected about 2015 has not been not fixed.